# Amazon Web Services: CloudFront Report, other than 'Popular Objects'

Tags: amazon-web-services, report, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a possibility in the AWS Interface to see a **report overview** on all (or any) hosted files?

Actually the same that is shown in **CloudFront > CloudFront Popular Objects Report**, but for all the 'not so popular' files. Or just one specific file.

[expected values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTPLo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront only knows about files that are requested. Files that are not requested will remain unknown to CloudFront.

CloudFront creates log files. You could then index your S3 bucket to create a comparison of files that are not accessed or accessed infrequently.

Amazon Athena is a nice product for processing log files stored in S3 and supports SQL for queries.